# How can I make changes to numerous branches at the same time in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch, checkin, tfs-power-tools

Recently I've been needing to check stuff in to 3/4 branches every time I check something into TFS. Since the code base for each branch is virtually the same is there anyway I can just do one check in to all branches and visual studio will just ask me to confirm any conflicts as part of some sort of merge? It would save me having to go to the branch, find the specific file, check it out then manually make the changes. Surely there must be a better option!

I saw something with power tools where you could unshelve into different branches but I couldn't get it working. What is the formatting for target and source when using "tfpt unshelve" from command prompt? However I don't think this would check out the file too. Sorry if this isn't clear!

Comment: a picture of your branching hierarchy would help. Surely you check your change in to 1 branch and then merge the changes to the other branches. If you're manually checking the changes in to multiple branches you’re asking for trouble (merge conflicts) when someone tries to merge the branches at a later date